# FaceRecognition with javacv android

Tags: android, javacv

I'm following javacv Face Detection/Recognition code, there is confusion regarding face recognition.. What I'm doing is (Sorry if it sounds stupid but I'm stuck)

1) Detect Face crop it and save it to sdcard and place path in learn.txt file (Learning part)

2) Detect Face crop it and find it in existing faces whether it exists or not, but it always return nearest position even if the face doesn't exist in sample faces..

what I'm doing wrong?

```
// Method, I'm using to recognize face

public Integer recognizeFace(Bitmap face, Context context) {
    Log.i(TAG, "===========================================");
    Log.i(TAG, "recognizeFace (single face)");


    float[] projectedTestFace;
    float confidence = 0.0f;
    int nearest = -1; // closest match -- -1 for nothing. 
    int iNearest;


    if (trainPersonNumMat == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "NUMBER OF EIGENS: " + nEigens);
    // project the test images onto the PCA subspace
    projectedTestFace = new float[nEigens];
    // Start timing recognition
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    testFaceImg = bmpToIpl(face);
//  saveBmp(face, "blah");
    // convert Bitmap it IplImage
    //testFaceImg = IplImage.create(face.getWidth(), face.getHeight(),
    //      IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);

    //face.copyPixelsToBuffer(testFaceImg.getByteBuffer());

    // project the test image onto the PCA subspace
    cvEigenDecomposite(testFaceImg, // obj
            nEigens, // nEigObjs
            new PointerPointer(eigenVectArr), // eigInput (Pointer)
            0, // ioFlags
            null, // userData
            pAvgTrainImg, // avg
            projectedTestFace); // coeffs

    // LOGGER.info("projectedTestFace\n" +
    // floatArrayToString(projectedTestFace));
    Log.i(TAG, "projectedTestFace\n" + floatArrayToString(projectedTestFace));

    final FloatPointer pConfidence = new FloatPointer(confidence);
    iNearest = findNearestNeighbor(projectedTestFace, new FloatPointer(pConfidence));
    confidence = pConfidence.get();
    // truth = personNumTruthMat.data_i().get(i);
    nearest = trainPersonNumMat.data_i().get(iNearest); // result

    // get endtime and calculate time recognition process takes
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = endTime - startTime;
    double seconds = (double) duration / 1000000000.0;
    Log.i(TAG, "recognition took: " + String.valueOf(seconds));

    Log.i(TAG, "nearest = " + nearest + ". Confidence = " + confidence);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Nearest: "+nearest+" Confidence: "+confidence, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Save the IplImage so we can see what it looks like
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "/sdcard/saved_images/" + nearest + " " + String.valueOf(seconds) + " " + String.valueOf(confidence) + " " + n + ".jpg";

    Log.i(TAG, "Saving image as: " + fname);

    cvSaveImage(fname, testFaceImg);


    return nearest;
} // end of recognizeFace
```

**EDIT** The confidence is always negative!

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what do you get out? Did you already solve the problem?

Comment: @Brandli, I didn't actually I had to leave that project due to some reasons, still wondering what point I was missing!